# WPF User Control Losing Focus

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I have a UserControl which allows the user to enter data. I'm trying to enforce that when focus is removed from the user control, data validation  takes place and the user has to go back and correct the data or cancel the changes made.

I've tried using the usercontrol LostFocus, but this appears to be called every time the user moves between controls inside the UserControl, not just when the UserControl loses focus. Also, there appears to be no way of seeing where the focus has moved to and to preventing the loss of focus - i.e. forcing the user to go back and correct things.

I come from a Winforms background, and this would be very easy to achieve but I can't see any easy way to do this in WPF.

Can someone please help?

Thanks

P.S. Sample code (which does not work...)

```
private void UserControl_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsModified)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            btnSave_Click(this, e);
        }

    }
```

The above is called whenever a control inside the user control has lost focus. So if the user control has say, 3 textboxes, when the user moves between each one, this event is called each time. I only want to process the event if the focus is moved away from the User Control itself. Then I want to prompt the user along the lines of "Please save or cancel your changes before moving away from this page." And, then only if focus is moved to another part of the application and not, for example, if the user has ALT-Tabbed away from the application.

Comment: That is *not* something we have to do in WPF... or not manually like that anyway. Please take a look at the [`Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.

Comment: As is customary on this website, you may find that you get more answers if you follow the descriptions on the [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page of the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help). Please add a [simplified example of your code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that still clearly demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Thanks for this, but I had already looked at this area and it isn't suitable for what I want and I'm confused by your comment "that is not something we have to do in WPF". What I'm wanting to do is not unusual  - the data is only committed once the user clicks Submit. This is NOT the problem. The issue is how to prevent the user from moving away from the control until they have committed or cancelled the changes. So, as far as I can, see this has nothing to do with data binding, but UI control.

Comment: You don't have to manually handle events to kick off data validation in WPF... not if it's done properly. Please read the [Data Validation in 3.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2007/10/02/data-validation-in-3-5.aspx) page on MSDN Blogs for more help... I'd concentrate on the more useful `IDataErrorInfo` parts of the page and maybe even look at the [`INotifyDataErrorInfo` page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN too.

Comment: Thanks again for this comment. I already use IDataErrorInfo and other data validation mechanisms extensively throughout the application. This is NOT an issue or question regarding data validation. I simply do not want the user to move away from a user control until they have saved (in which case the database would be updated) or cancelled the changes. Please, move away from Data Validation - this is not what I'm asking about! Data has already been validated BUT NOT committed to the database. I want the user to HAVE to click Save Or Cancel before moving to another area/screen of the app.

Comment: BTW, I'm using the incredible Modern UI library. To see the problem, download their demo app. You'll see the user can move between pages/frames/sections without any hindrance - not good if the user decides to start entering data on a page and then move to another page leaving their edits in a state of limbo... I want to stop this - if the user starts editing data on a page they must finish before they can move away from it. This seems an impossible task in WPF - many window messages/events taken for granted in Winforms/Delphi/Vb are simply not exposed in WPF.

Comment: *This seems an impossible task in WPF*... far from it.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, so what I now understand from your comments is that you simply want to stop a user from leaving a view before they either save or cancel the current editing action. For future reference, it is always best to start your question with your overall goal... something like the sentence above. *Then* you go on to say what you have tried... the question text that you currently have. Your question would have been answered immediately if you had done this.

So how can we achieve this? It could be pretty simple really, but it will depend on the way that you change views. When a user in my applications changes a view, they click on a `Button`. That `Button` has a related `Command` and in the `ICommand` property in the view model, I load the relevant view. Now whether you use `Command`s or events when the user wants to change the view is irrelevant.

It's at this point that *you* have control in the application. You can simply not load the view if the data item has not been saved, or the editing has not been cancelled. I assume that if it was cancelled, then you'd load a different view anyway, so you'd only have to check to see if the item had been saved or not before loading the requested view.

If you choose, you could also set a property at this stage to display a message in the UI that the user has to save or cancel before changing the view. That could be done as simply as data binding a `string` that starts off empty to a `TextBlock` in the UI and setting it to the message when the user tries to load another view.

Comment: Thanks but this still doesn't prevent the user from moving to another page. It just means that the fact that they're editing is recorded.

Comment: How does it not? I said *It's at this point that you have control in the application. You can simply not load the view if the data item has not been saved, or the editing has not been cancelled*... how does not loading the new view *not* prevent the user from changing the view, or page as you call it?